# Showing exponentials are dependent functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that $e^{mt}$ and $e^{nt}$ are dependent iff $m=n$.

Thoughts. Well, obviously, if $m=n$, then $e^{mt}-e^{nt}=0$ and so they are dependent.

On the other hand, let us suppose, they are depndent. that is there is some constant A so that $e^{nt} = A e^{mt}$ this implies that

$$ e^{(n-m)t} = A $$

And so $ (n-m) t = \ln A $. This is true for every $t$. For example if $t=1$, we obtain $\ln A = n-m$ but if $t=2$, then $\ln A = 2(n-m)$ so that $1=2$ which is absurd and thus $n=m$

is this correct?

Comment: Yes it seems so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is right. Another way to do is the following: Suppose they are dependent. Then there exists some constant $A$ such that $e^{nt}=Ae^{mt}$. Since this is true for every $t$, making $t=0$ we obtain $A=1$ and then $e^{nt}=e^{mt}$. It follows that $n=m$ since we can make $t=1$ and apply the $\log$ function.

Comment: Would be the same procedure if we replace say $e^{ax}$ with $ x e^{ax} $  ?

Comment: @James yes, even also with the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ defined by $f_1(t)=te^{at}$ and $f_2(t)=e^{bt}$ (not necessarily need that $a\neq b$ in this case).

Answer (score 1):

@James. It is true that $e^{m_1t},\dots, e^{m_kt}$ are linearly independent iff all $m_i$'s are different.
Suppose $\sum_{j=1}^ka_je^{m_jt}=0$ and all $m_i$'s are different. Then, differentiating we get, $\sum_{j=1}^ka_jm_j^ne^{m_jt}=0$ for all $t$  and $n\in\mathbb N.$ P Without loss of generality assume $m_1<m_2<\dots<m_k.$ We have $\sum_{j=1}^ka_jm_j^ne^{(m_j-m_k)t}=0$ for all $t$  and $n\in\mathbb N.$ Take $t\to\infty$ to obtain $a_k=0.$ Similarly, you also have $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_{k-1}=0.$

The other direction is very easy to see.